# Hybrid MapKit map default pins tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mapkit, mkannotation

is there a way to tap on the default points of interest and showing its popup using MapKit?

I'm attaching a screenshot of how it works on Apple Map App, if you tap on the POI icon.

[image: Apple Maps]

If you try to do the same on your own App with the same map type you see the point of interest but nothing happens when you try to interact with it.

Is it possible somehow to interact with them, or, at least to hide them?

Thanks,
Luigi

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `canShowCallout` property to `YES` in the

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

for each `MKAnnotationView`, except for the the `MKUserLocation`